# Conditions on Matrix invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Given a matrix $A$ of size $n\times m$ with $m<<n$ linearly independent columns and hence of full rank. Now a column $a$ is added to $A$. How can we determine the new matrix $A$ of size $n\times (m+1)$ is still invertible?

I know one way is to check if the value $[a^Ta-(A^Ta)^T(A^TA)^{\dagger}(A^Ta)]$ is non-zero.
But I don't want to compute the pseudo-inverse $(A^TA)^{\dagger}$.
Nor do I want to compute the determinant which takes $O(n^3)$ complexity.

Is there any computationally efficient way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be using "invertible" to mean "of full rank"? The concept of invertibility only applies to diagonal matrices.

Comment: @joriki To *square* matrices.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, of course, yes, to square matrices :-)

Comment: There are methods for updating the QR decomposition and singular value decomposition when a new column or row is added to the original matrix; you might want to look them up.

Comment: @Guess can you suggest some references.

Comment: I was nudging you to search for them yourself, as I have now given you the words you should be looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Vinayak Abrol , do you understand that you write ?

1. As joriki wrote, your matrix $A$ is not invertible but has full rank, that implies that $A^TA$ is invertible (why the pseudo inverse ?).

EDIT.  2. The calculation of the rank of a matrix $(n\times m+1)$ is in $O(n(m+1)^2)$ by Gaussian elimination; moreover, there is a randomized algorithm in $O((m+1)n+(m+1)^3)$, that is much better than your $O(n^3)$.

3. The calculation of $(A^TA)^{-1}$ is the calculation of $A^TA$ (with complexity $nm^2$) and the calculation of its inverse (with complexity $m^3$). Finally the total complexity is $nm^2$ and absolutely not $n^3$.
4. Consequently, to verify that the condition $||a||^2-a^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ta\not= 0$ is satisfied has complexity $O(nm^2)$, that is essentially $O(n)$; how to do better ?

Comment: The conditioned i mentioned doesn't give determinant but like determinant it can be used to check linear independance. And now i have made the edits in the question.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Sorry i didn't mentioned that i am going to do this iteratively. Thus $m$ grows after each iteration and will eventually go $>n$. I wanted to do something with complexity linear or quadratic in $m$ even if $m$ is large. Anyway your comments helped a lots.